# VS 2019 Controller IAction Add View scaffolders stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.4.5

On an IActionResult in a controller you can right click on the Action name and select Add View.
This was working but now I get an error:
'There are no `scaffolders` supported for this item.'

I know how to do it manually and I'm not looking for a work around.

How do I get the `scaffolders` to work again?

NOTE: Just updated to VS 16.4.6 and it did not resolve the problem.